# xcode app: safari won't go to app store link

Tags: xcode, hyperlink, app-store

I put a link on a button in an iPhone app (xcode 4.2). The link does open a safari window successfully to other websites, but not to the iTunes Preview pages to specific apps. This problem occurs if the link is entered directly in the code. It also occurs on an indirect link to the app store page--i.e. a page with a working link to an iTunes app page gets there fine from Safari on the mac itself, but not when the page loads up on the iPhone simulator and the same link is clicked. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying this on the simulator exclusively? I'm not entirely certain, but it's possible that you're linking to the page that tries to open the app store, which the simulator does not have access to.

Comment: Thanks, XenElement. I'll try it on the device. Unfortunately, I have to copy it to another computer to do that because the old iMac I work on can't take Lion, and the version of x-code on it won't acknowledge my iPad and iPods after I (foolishly?) updated their iOS. I'll report what happens.

Comment: Thanks, XenElement. You were right. The links to other sites work in the simulator, but not links to the app store preview page. But they do work on the IOS device itself (i.e. running from XCODE). Strange! If you want to answer officially, I can then give you a check mark.